# How to get Min() and Max() DateTime for a Column which can be repeated after certain occurrences

Tags: sql, database

I need to find the Min and Max ActionDatetime. Below is my current table Table

Table:A

| LOGID | PROCESSINSTANCEID | USERID | aCTIONdATETIME | ACTIVITYNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20,450 | COB-0000002024-process | 23 | 7/14/2021 11:17:37 AM | Branch_Maker |
| 20,451 | COB-0000002024-process | 23 | 7/14/2021 11:17:37 AM | Branch_Maker |
| 20,456 | COB-0000002024-process | 23 | 7/14/2021 12:17:47 PM | Branch_Maker |
| 20,464 | COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/14/2021 12:18:42 PM | Compliance_Review |
| 20,467 | COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/14/2021 12:19:12 PM | Compliance_Review |
| 20,475 | COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/14/2021 12:19:19 PM | Branch_Maker_Correction |
| 20,476 | COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/14/2021 12:19:19 PM | Branch_Maker_Correction |
| 20,481 | COB-0000002024-process | 23 | 7/14/2021 12:20:41 PM | Branch_Maker_Correction |
| 20,491 | COB-0000002024-process | 24 | 7/14/2021 12:25:35 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 20,492 | COB-0000002024-process | 24 | 7/14/2021 12:25:35 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 20,493 | COB-0000002024-process | 24 | 7/14/2021 12:26:42 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 20,494 | COB-0000002024-process | 24 | 7/14/2021 12:26:42 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 20,500 | COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/14/2021 12:27:54 PM | AMC_Maker |
| 20,579 | COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/15/2021 1:17:05 PM | AMC_Maker |
| 20,580 | COB-0000002024-process | 24 | 7/14/2021 1:18:05 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 20,581 | COB-0000002024-process | 24 | 7/14/2021 1:27:05 PM | Branch_Checker |
| 20,586 | COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/15/2021 1:37:22 PM | AMC_Checker |
| 20,587 | COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/15/2021 1:47:22 PM | AMC_Checker |

Need something like below:
As Branch Checker appeared twice after certain interval, so need to calculate Branch Checker min and max actiondatetime every time it occurs post group of interval.
Also, we need to show only the last user ID per ActivityName per occurence

| PROCESSINSTANCEID | USERID | min aCTIONdATETIME | max aCTIONdATETIME | ACTIVITYNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COB-0000002024-process | 24 | 7/14/2021 11:17:37 AM | 7/14/2021 12:17:47 PM | Branch_Maker |
| COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/14/2021 12:18:42 PM | 7/14/2021 12:19:12 PM | Compliance_Review |
| COB-0000002024-process | 24 | 7/14/2021 12:19:19 PM | 7/14/2021 12:20:41 PM | Branch_Maker_Correction |
| COB-0000002024-process | 32 | 7/14/2021 12:25:35 PM | 7/14/2021 12:26:42 PM | Branch_Checker |
| COB-0000002024-process | 6 | 7/14/2021 12:27:54 PM | 7/15/2021 1:17:05 PM | AMC_Maker |
| COB-0000002024-process | 48 | 7/14/2021 1:18:05 PM | 7/14/2021 1:27:05 PM | Branch_Checker |
| COB-0000002024-process | 52 | 7/15/2021 1:37:22 PM | 7/15/2021 1:47:22 PM | AMC_Checker |

Comment: You seem to want to do "gaps and islands" although the user ids don't match up.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get the last occurrence per Activity Name.
First ocurrence would be the same query with a MIN.

```
SELECT * FROM A T1
JOIN (
    SELECT * ACTIVITYNAME, MAX(ACTIONDATETIME) FROM A GROUP BY ACTIVITYNAME
) T2 ON T1.ACTIVITYNAME = T2.ACTIVITYNAME AND T1.ACTIONDATETIME= T2.ACTIONDATETIME
```

"post group of interval" it is not clear what you mean there

Comment: After Post Group of Interval means, as you can see in my Table A data, activityname Branch_Maker is repeating for 3 times before another activityname appears (its one interval), now I need to calculate min and max actiondatetime for 1st intrval for Branch_Maker, same goes with other ActivityName also. BUT, if you see the Activityname Branch_Checker appeared repeated times (in 2 difrnt intervals), means one before Branch_Maker Correction and one after AMC_Maker, so in this case I need min/max for both Branc_Checker group, one for before Brnch_Mker Crctn and one aftr amc

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
PROCESSINSTANCEID,  
USERID,     
ACTIVITYNAME,
min(aCTIONdATETIME) over (partition by USERID, activityname) as min_aCTIONdATETIME,
max(aCTIONdATETIME) over (partition by USERID, activityname) as max_aCTIONdATETIME
from A
```